# No windows appearing when using WxWidgets on MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I am having an issue in using WxWidgets, my code is as follows:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <iostream>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
};

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame("Hello World", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340));
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
}

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world, why isn't there a window showing?\n";
}
```

It compiles fine, but no window appears except from the output: `Hello world, why isn't there a window showing?` but it doesn't show any GUI window.
[image: The only window that pops up]

I have been using vcpkg on MSVC to get the WxWidgets, does any one know how I could resolve these errors?

Comment: Are you creating a desktop application or console application?

Comment: @RobertShepherd, also don't use vcpkg - it may be buggy. Compile the library yourself. Pretty easy and straightforward. You also loose the abiluity to properly debug the application and access to different sample code for using the library.

Comment: @Aamir I am using it for a desktop appliction

Comment: The application type of your Visual Studio project is most likely console application, not desktop application like it should be. Also you are not supposed to have a `main` function in a desktop application, and the fact that your `main` gets executed in the first place further proves that it is a console application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building your application as a console application (`/subsystem:console` linker option), meaning that its entry point is `main()`, instead of building it as a Windows application (`/subsystem:windows`). You can do it like this, but then you're responsible for calling the library entry point (`wxEntry()`) yourself.

But unless you have a good reason to do it like this, you should just change the application type in the IDE/linker option if you use makefiles or something else to make it a Windows application. You should then remove `main()` entirely as it won't be used -- and its absence won't result in linking errors for a Windows application.